# How to create AWS Cloudwatch Logs Metric Filter Pattern with Spaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am trying to create a cloudwatch log filter pattern to send log lines onto slack via sns. I followed the instructions here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html

However, I can't seem to match any logs with the pattern in questions in AWS's pattern tester. Please see screenshot. I would like to match log patterns with spaces on either side of severe or fatal e.g.:

"this is a severe error"

However, I don't want it to match log lines with characters on either side of fatal or severe: e.g.

"this is a [fatal] warning"

[image]

Comment: The **filter pattern** field is not looking for text to match. Rather, it is looking for information on how the row is formatted, what the field names are and what values to match for the filter. Can you please provide us with some complete sample rows from the input file? (Both ones that match your desired pattern and other lines. We need to see how the fields are defined and formatted.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein So, if I set the filter pattern as just: " fatal ", it matches exactly how I'd want it to match for example the following lines are matched:

This is a fatal error

This is a fatal warning

However, the following patterns are not matched because there are no spaces between fatal:

this is a [fatal] warning
fatal error detected

However, I want to add or expression so that we have multiple keywords to match e.g. " severe " or " fatal " or " error " the documentation specifies the use of ? for or expression but this is not working

Comment: Do you lines contain only free-form text, or does it contain delimited fields? Can you please provide us with some complete sample rows from the input file?

Comment: only free form text, I would like to create a filter pattern as follows:

Match any logs with " severe " or " SEVERE " or " fatal " or " FATAL " 

So, far I have the following pattern which is not working ?" severe "?" SEVERE "?" FATAL"?" fatal " it only seems to accept two double quotes and can't have multiple.

Comment: According to the documentation, `?` is used to signify an `OR` condition. It does not seem to be the traditional wildcard character meaning "any character". It _might_ work if you try: `?fatal ?severe - "[fatal]" - "[severe]"`